# IIS/C# website share authentication with Tomcat/Java website - same top level URL

Tags: c#, java, tomcat, iis, single-sign-on

We have several Intranet websites that use MVC + .NET windows authentication. And then we have some Java based apps developed by 3rd party - which can be configured to use LDAP authentication. Both sets of apps use the same company URL, for instance, dotnet-app.company.org and java-app.company.org, and both sets use the same username.

Once a user has been authenticated against a .NET app, is there any way I can "post" that user information to Tomcat which can then generate a cookie for the user so they don't have to authenticate twice?

I have authorization to modify code on the .NET app only not on the Java app.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for a `one sign-in` option like on gmail and other google services. And yes, cookies are what you must be looking at.

I don't know how java authentication works(I assume it is Session based), and there is where you must read in user cookie information to get authentication details. On .NET, you will have to write custom logic in `FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate` in `Global.asax` file.

Comment: that's right I'm looking for single sign on or the `one sign in` in Google. I can only configure the java app to start accepting LDAP as authentication mechanism, I cannot modify its code to look/parse/add session or cookie. My knowledge in Apache web app server is very limited and I was wondering if there are some mods out there that can be added to the server to accept the .NET generated authentication and make them cookie-happy ;)